# Two views, two controllers, one model, different re_direct in each controller based on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have comments controller that creates comments on show.html.erb of a book controller.

Users can also post comments on another view, which is different from show.html.erb above but still uses the same comment form. This is index.html.erb for postcomments controller that inherits from comments controller. I created this just for this purpose.

My purpose is to, when comment is saved, redirect to show.html.erb (book) when comment was created there and redirect to index.html.erb (postcomments)when comment was created there -- that is to say, remain on the same page.

Right now redirect to show.html.erb (book) works fine. But when I create comment on index.html.erb (postcomments), it redirects to show.html.erb (book).

comments controller (only relevant section):

```rb
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to comment_create_redirect_path, notice: "Success!~"
        else 
            redirect_to book_path(@post.book.id), alert: "Failure!" 
        end

    end

    private
        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:text)
        end

    private
        def comment_create_redirect_path
            book_path(@post.book.id)
        end
```

postcomments controller (full; I've tried adding the entire create action with redirect switched; didn't work):

```rb
class PostcommentsController < CommentsController

    def index
        @posts = Post.all
    end

    private
    def comment_create_redirect_path
        postcomments_path
    end
```

index.html.erb (postcomments, relevant section):

```
  <%= form_for(post.comments.build, url: "/posts/#{post.id}/comments") do |form| %>
    <p>
      <%= form.text_area :text %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit "Post comment"%>
    </p>
  <% end %>

  <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <%= comment.user.try(:email) %>
    <%= comment.text %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
```

routes:

```rb
  resources :users do
    resources :books, shallow: true 
  end

  resources :books do
    resources :posts, shallow: true
  end

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, shallow: true
  end

  resources :postcomments, shallow: true
```

Please let me know if you'd like anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get referer path and redirect action to this path:

```
# comments_controller.rb

def comment_create_redirect_path
  return root_path if request.try(:referer).blank?
  URI(request.referer).path
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `redirect_back` helper. You need to provide a fallback location.

```
redirect_back fallback_location: @post.book
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_back

Comment: Thank you - this works, but simply because @demir posted the answer first (that one also works), I have chosen that as the answer. But I will upvote yours!